# Поле, подобное chekedlistbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно создать поле, подобное checkedlistbox, но с возможностью пользователя изменять в нем текст. Как это сделать без большого количества дополнительных кнопок, полей и т.п.?

Comment: Перейти на WPF?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете попробовать реализовать свой UserControl. Если устраивает checkedlistbox, но нужен дополнительный функционал - наследуйте и добавляйте.

Ссылки:

- [О UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Пример создания контрола - 1](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-authoring-a-composite-control-with-visual-csharp)
- [Пример создания контрола - 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms171926.aspx)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]